# How to fix this Subproject Path: CordovaLib Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I use mac Sierra
How to fix this Error

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Error: spawn EACCES 
[image: Mac Screen]

Answer (score 19):

You will need to make `gradlew` executable **which resides in `platforms` folder in your ionic project at following path**

```
/Users/*<your ionic project path>*/platforms/android/gradlew
```

> For MAC

```
sudo chmod 755 /Users/<your ionic project path>/platforms/android/gradlew
```

where [chmod 755](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/chmod-755.shtml)  stands for : you allow everyone to read and execute the file, and the file owner is allowed to write to the file as well. If you apply 755 to a directory, it means that everyone can go to it and get its file listing.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by making gradle executable

```
chmod +x ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem in my project. I used the following steps for making build successfully.
Steps:
1. Go to your project directory.
2. Go to android folder by running `cd platforms/android/`.
3. Add read, write and execute permission to gradlew file. For this run `chmod 777 gradlew`.
4. Go to your project directory again by running `cd ../../`.
5. Run command for build `ionic cordova build android`.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by giving permissions on app folder
try:

```
sudo chmod -R u+rwx /yourIonicAppFolder
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Setting your Applications folder as writable by anyone is a huge security risk.

Comment: @MatusalemMarques  Keep in mind i mean the ionic app folder, not the "Applications" folder. first option is just a bad idea, second, indeed is a huge security risk, but not what i'm suggesting ;) 

The answer works anyway so edited to make only writable by owner. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: a+rwx is a security risk for any location containing code a user might run, be it the system Applications folder or any other. Your edit looks more clear and sensible.